# node.js + express: serving static files from different "user/connection" folders

Tags: node.js, express

I serve a SPA over an office webserver (node.js+express), but these static files doesn't came from a static public folder. The webserver gets signal from another server, that new a new client is downloadable. The office server get the archive and extracts it to a new folder (name: client/clientxxxxx.zip_content/). All new connections should use the new folder, but the old ones have to use the version they used at the first connection.

I think I have a problem with the identification of the same user/connection, because the SPA will be stateless and I can't change the statice files. PHP has an automatic for the session (id in cookie or as get variable). Is there something for express? And how to serve all files from different main folders?

**My simple solution:**

A test with a HTML and an image in a subfolder, it works with [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) (Thx Alex) and a simple `sendFile`.

```
app.use(session({
    genid: function(req) {
        return uuid.v4();
    },
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
        maxAge: null
    },
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'this is not a secret'
}));
app.get(['/','/:path*'], function (req, res, next) {
    req.session.clientPath = req.session.clientPath || path.join(main.paths.client, main.versions.client + '_content');
    var clientFile = path.normalize(path.join(req.session.clientPath, req.path === '/' ? '/index.html' : req.path));
    if (clientFile.indexOf(main.paths.client) === 0 && fs.existsSync(clientFile)) {
        res.sendFile(clientFile);
    } else {
        res.status(404).send('Not found');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not just overwrite the old files? For express sessions: https://github.com/expressjs/session

Comment: It would be a bad idea if the SPA load its HTML from the old version, then the server writes the new files, and the new JavaScript files are incompatible. Thanks for the link.

Comment: The solution then, is to create a reference to a newly named server folder, possibly in a database table. Say the unzipping process will add an entry to a DB once it's finished, and the Express app will pull that data to point to the new directory. You could use internal messaging to tell Express / Node to get the latest directory name.